# Mysql Error Code 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I'm having some issues with a mysql query.
I'm trying to join together multiple tables.
In one table, I have a list of successful online customers, and on another table I have a table which has the traffic source from which it came. I'm trying to track which customers came from a certain ad. So I want to query those new customers who came on a certain date and from a specific campaign.

```
SELECT keyword, COUNT(keyword) FROM in_clicks AS ic WHERE ic.create_date LIKE '%2011-08-19%' GROUP BY ic.keyword ORDER BY COUNT(ic.keyword) DESC
       INNER JOIN leads AS l ON ls.lead_id = l.id 
       INNER JOIN lead_status AS ls ON ls.lead_id = ls.id
       INNER JOIN ads AS a ON ic.ad_id = a.id
       INNER JOIN ad_groups AS ag ON a.ad_group_id = ag.id
       INNER JOIN campaigns AS c ON ag.campaign_id = c.id;
```

I ran the above code and got the following error.

```
Error Code: 1064
'INNER JOIN leads AS l ON ls.lead_id = l.id Innner Join lead_status AS ls' at line 2
```

Comment: ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax.

Comment: are you *sure* that's your query? thee isn't "Innner" in your query (instead of "nnner")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should run better :-).

```
SELECT keyword, COUNT(keyword) 
FROM in_clicks AS ic 
       INNER JOIN leads AS l ON ls.lead_id = l.id 
       INNER JOIN lead_status AS ls ON ls.lead_id = ls.id
       INNER JOIN ads AS a ON ic.ad_id = a.id
       INNER JOIN ad_groups AS ag ON a.ad_group_id = ag.id
       INNER JOIN campaigns AS c ON ag.campaign_id = c.id;
WHERE ic.create_date LIKE '%2011-08-19%' 
GROUP BY ic.keyword 
ORDER BY COUNT(ic.keyword) DESC
```

The order is: SELECT .. FROM ... JOIN ... WHERE ... GROUP BY .. HAVING .. ORDER BY .. LIMIT

Answer (score 2):

All of the `INNER JOIN` clauses need to be between your `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses.  It's syntactically invalid to use `INNER JOIN` following `WHERE` in the same query.

As pointed out by Bohemian, you also have a syntax error: `Innner` should be `INNER` (you have one to many `n` characters).