# DataTables PHP Server Processing

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am creating a DataTables using Datables JQuery.I was able to view my data fine. The issue i have is that i cannot search the table when i have GROUP BY on my query .I receive Error 1064. Any input is appreciated.

```
<?php


    $aColumns = array( 'accountname', 'accountAddress1', 'accountAddress2', 'accountCity', 'accountState', 'accountZip', 'accountphone', 'accountemail', 'accountWebSite', 'accountFax','tasktitle');



  $sIndexColumn = "accountname";
  $sTable = "accounts";
  $sJoin = "LEFT JOIN tasks on accounts.accountname = tasks.taskresource GROUP BY accounts.accountname";
  $gaSql['user']       = "xxxx";
  $gaSql['password']   = "xxxx";
  $gaSql['db']         = "xxx";
  $gaSql['server']     = "localhost";

   /* 
   * Local functions
   */

  function fatal_error ( $sErrorMessage = '' )
  {
    header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' 500 Internal Server Error' );
    die( $sErrorMessage );
  }

  /* 
   * MySQL connection
   */
  if ( ! $gaSql['link'] = mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) )
  {
    fatal_error( 'Could not open connection to server' );
  }

  if ( ! mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) )
  {
    fatal_error( 'Could not select database ' );
  }


  /* 
   * Paging
   */
  $sLimit = "";
  if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
  {
    $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
      intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
  }


  /*
   * Ordering
   */
  $sOrder = "";
  if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
  {
    $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
    {
      if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
      {
        $sOrder .= "`".$aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."` ".
          ($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";
      }
    }

    $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
    if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
    {
      $sOrder = "";
    }
  }


  /* 
   * Filtering
   * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
   * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
   * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
   */
  $sWhere = "";
  if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
  {
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
      $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';
  }

  /* Individual column filtering */
  for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
  {
    if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
    {
      if ( $sWhere == "" )
      {
        $sWhere = "WHERE ";
      }
      else
      {
        $sWhere .= " AND ";
      }
      $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
    }
  }


  /*
   * SQL queries
   * Get data to display
   */
  $sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode("`, `", $aColumns))."`
    FROM   $sTable
    $sJoin
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
    ";
    // $sQuery2 = "
    // SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode("`, `", $aColumns))."`
    // FROM   $sTable
    // $sWhere
    // $sOrder
    // $sLimit
    // ";
  $rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error() );

  /* Data set length after filtering */
  $sQuery = "
    SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
  ";
  $rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
  $aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
  $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

  /* Total data set length */
  $sQuery = "
    SELECT COUNT(`".$sIndexColumn."`)
    FROM   $sTable
  ";
  $rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
  $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
  $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


  /*
   * Output
   */
  $output = array(
    "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
    "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
    "aaData" => array()
  );

  while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
  {
    $row = array();   
     //$row[] =  $OpenAccountTasks;
    $row[] = '<img src="assets/advanced-datatable/examples/examples_support/details_open.png">';
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
      if ( $aColumns[$i] == "accountname" )
      {
        /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
       //$row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        $row[] = '<a href="AccountProfile.php?acctname=' .$aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ].'">' . $aRow[$aColumns[$i]] . '</a>';
      }
      else if ($aColumns[$i] =="tasktitle")
      {
        $taskRow = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM tasks WHERE taskresource = '$aRow[accountname]' && taskstatus = 'Active'");
        $taskCountResult = mysql_result($taskRow, 0);
        if ($taskCountResult == 0) {
                  $row[] =  '<span class="label label-success label-mini">'.$taskCountResult.'</span>';
        }
        else{
                  $row[] =  '<span class="label label-danger label-mini">'.$taskCountResult.'</span>';
        }
      }
      else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
      {
        /* General output */
        $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
      }
    }
    $output['aaData'][] = $row;
  }

  echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Was bale to figure it out. Thanks to Johan 
[Mysql Error Code 1064](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154249/mysql-error-code-1064)

Created a  $sGroup = "GROUP BY accounts.accountname";